# Validates uniqueness but only when 'Admin' is selected as username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to avoid that somebody can create an user with the username 'Admin'. I use this username as Host to control some functions of my application. I know there is a expression to validate the uniqueness of an model record:

```
validates_uniqueness_of
```

But i only want that the username 'Admin' cant be created twice. I hope somebody has an idea! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditionals in your validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) to do the following:

```
class Model
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, if: :admin?

  def admin?
    username.downcase == 'admin'
  end
end
```

With that said, they'd take away my developer card if I didn't discourage you from doing this.

Basing an admin account solely on whether the username is admin is setting yourself up for your security being compromised. Have a look at something like [`ActiveAdmin`](http://www.activeadmin.info/) for managing your administrator accounts so that they're at the *very least* separated from your user accounts.

Comment: Sorry, but i wrote exactly your code into my model and i always get the error `undefined method `admin?'` do you have any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Or just   `validates_uniqueness_of :username, if: -> {username == 'admin'}` in your model.